# lubuntu change default runlevel

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, runlevel

How can I change the default runlevel in Lubuntu 14.04? Some say by changing the inittab file but, I can't find any /etc/inittab file in my computer.

Comment: What if I want a certain runlevel e.g 3?

Comment: And how to restore it back?

Comment: Replace `text` with `3` in the steps from that question.

Comment: Remove `text` and use `quiet splash`. Be warned that runlevels 2,3,4 and 5 are equivalent in Ubuntu. Don't expect any difference.

Comment: Ok, Hope I don't screw it up and can boot to gui later.

Comment: On the grub prompt, you can always edit the actual line by pressing `e` on an entry. That will help you get things back on track.